# Rxdart CombineLatest combine with optional field

Tags: flutter, observable, bloc, rxdart, combinelatest

I need help, how can I use `combinelatest` in Rxdart flutter which I have an optional field to combine, for example:
In my form I have 4 widget, the widget in my form are:

- textfield1
- checkbox
- textfield2
- Raisebutton

Two `textfields` and `checkbox` using `BehaviourSubject`, then `RaiseButton` using `combineLatest` [usually using combineLatest3 for this kind of approach], but there are some condition in my case, when the checkbox is checked textfield2 is show and the checkbox is unchecked, textfield2 is hidden/ destroy. so in my case the textfield2 is optional, when the textfield2 is there, then included in check of `combinelatest`, if the field is not there it's not check by `combineLatest`

Comment: Have you checked the `combineLatestList` method? [This](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/combineLatestList.html) might help.

Comment: You can add a `combineLatest` with `checkbox_2.isChecked ? controller1.text : controller1.text + controller2.text`

Comment: @SiddharthPatankar I tried the `combineLatestList` but it has no control over what needed to be return and needed `.listen()`
@Ferdi can you provide me some worked example, I tried the sample logic it's wrong, can't be combined with 2 controller in the iterable

Comment: @Ferdi is it possible like this?
`checkbox_2.isChecked ? controller2.text : null` i tried this way i got stream can't null